# Realm + swift sorting

Tags: iphone, swift, realm

Wondering if anyone have faced & solved this issue:

**Description**

I have 2 Classes called **Person** & **Dog** where a person can have more than one dog.

```
class Dog: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var age = 0
}


class Person: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var picture: NSData? = nil // optionals supported
  let dogs = List<Dog>()
}
```

According to my requirement, I need to fetch all objects from person.name == "ABC" & apply sort all dogs by Name.

Snippet:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

let result = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("name == %@","ABC").sorted(property : "name")
```

From the above snippet, sorting is done based on the person Name not on the  dog's Name.

How to create a filter & sort the list by dog name?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742434/filter-realm-objects-based-on-counting-listt/33744464) similar to your case?

Comment: @Ahmad Nope. In that link they are sorting with id which is self but in my case i need to sort by child class name

Answer (score 1):

`realm.objects(Person.self)` returns `Results<Person>`. Calling `sorted()` to `Results<Person>` means sort Person. If you'd like to sort `dogs`, you can retrieve element of person first, (e.g. `let person = result[0]`), then retrieve `dogs` property, call `sorted()` method to it.

```
let people = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("name == %@","ABC")
let person = people.first!
let sortedDogs = person.dogs.sorted(property : "name")
```